# Writing data to csv files using csvwriter crashed computer over weekend

Tags: python, csv, memory

I have a situation where there are 5 csv files open between 2 different Python programs running on a single computer. Lines of data are written to the csv files using using `writer.writerow(self.ROW_HEADER)`. Each csv file had approximately 1 column of data saved every second. The programs were set to run for weeks on end and after one weekend both programs had crashed without any error message. After reviewing the csv files, it appeared that data wasn't being written to some of the text files for a long time before the program crashed which makes me think it was a sort of memory overflow. Any recommendations on how to handle this?

Here's the class I instantiate to create each csv file.

```
class csv_file:
    
    ROW_HEADER = ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"]
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, path: str) -> None:
        self.file_name = f"{name}.csv"
        self.file_path = path
        self.file = None
        self.lock = threading.RLock()
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def create_file(self) -> None:
        '''
        Creates a csv file with the name and path specified in the constructor.
        Appends the row header to the file.
        '''
        with self.lock:
            os.makedirs(self.file_path, exist_ok=True) # Create the directory if it doesn't exist (nothing happens if it does)
            self.file = open(os.path.join(self.file_path, self.file_name), 'w')
            self.writer = csv.writer(self.file)
            self.writer.writerow(self.ROW_HEADER)

    def _create_row(self, row:list) -> None:
        '''
        Adds a row to the csv file. The row must be the same
        size as the row header.
        '''
        with self.lock:
            self.writer.writerow(row)

    def add_row(self, val1:float, val2:float, val3:float) -> None:
        with self.lock:
            row = []
            row.append(val1)
            row.append(val2)
            row.append(val3)
            self._create_row(row)
```

Comment: Without seeing how the files/programs interact can't say much, other than `_create_row` and `add_row` inefficently lock twice and could be just `with self.lock: self.writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])`.  Not clear a lock is even needed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you think it’s a threading issue? I’m pretty certain it’s a memory issue. It is possible that there is overlap in multiple threads writing to the same file so a lock is required. I agree that I don’t have to lock twice but is there a downside?

Comment: No idea, just commented on what I could see in the code.  You've only provided a class that is never instantiated and no steps to reproduce the issue.  There are no threads shown.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Just odd that it was working fine for a couple weeks then one morning everything crashed. I wasn't the one that saw the issue but I think it also crashed VSCode and other programs running on the computer. I basically see three levels of possible solutions - 1. Flush buffer intermittently, 2. Collect data a write chunks intermittently, 3. Write to a database instead

Comment: @jlaufer, definitely go the database route: it’s got everything you’re struggling with, or contemplating, already figured out.